# Detect SIM removal and update the application using broadcast notifications in iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is there any way to check SIM status continuously and send broadcast notifications to the application when ever the SIM is removed or inserted even when the app is killed   in iOS using XCODE6 ?

Comment: Checking continuously is probably not a good plan.

Comment: You can't check continuously. Apple won't let you run in the background for more than a few minutes, and even if you could it would drain the battery quickly.

Comment: Thank you.. I too noticed battery is draining very fast...

Answer (score 0):

You must add the CoreTelephony.framework and import
 CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h and CoreTelephony/CTCarrier.h
Then do the following to check if sim card is inserted

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netInfo = [[[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init] autorelease];
            CTCarrier *carrier = [netInfo subscriberCellularProvider];
            NSString *mnc = [carrier mobileNetworkCode]; 
            if (([mnc length] == 0) || ([mnc isEqualToString:@"65535"])) {
                // Device cannot place a call at this time.  SIM might be removed.
                return NO;
            } else {
                // Device can place a phone call
                return YES;
            }
```

Comment: Yah I am using the same way to find if SIM is present are not whenever I want . But I want my program to monitor SIM card continuously and do some action when ever SIM is removed